# Contains map in a list of maps

Tags: clojure

I have a list of maps and I need to know if one other map contains in this list:

List of maps:
`[{:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3}]`

My map:
`{:a 2}`

Expected output:
`true`

I had tried to use contains but do not work.
I come up with a solution but I don't think its a good one:

```
(map 
   (fn [x] 
      (if (= x {:a 1}) 
         true 
         false))
   [{:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3}])
```

The result of this code I'm getting a list of true or false, and I will need to see if contains one true in this list.

So my question is, exist some way easier to verify if exist a map in a list of maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question can be generalized to "how can I tell if a sequence contains a value?" [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) is good for this:

```
(some pred coll)
```

It returns the first logical true value from `pred` by invoking it with each item of `coll`.

For example, the predicate can be a simple equality check:

```
user=> (some #(= % {:foo 1})
             [{:foo 1} {:foo 2}])
true
```

It's also common to use sets as predicates:

> One common idiom is to use a set as pred, for example
>   this will return `:fred` if `:fred` is in the sequence, otherwise nil:
>   `(some #{:fred} coll)`